# Encoding problem processing Microsoft Word files in Python

Tags: python, ms-word, character-encoding

My goal is to extract specific information out of the array of Word Documents, which i use Regex for. In the process I have encountered a following problem: those Word Documents contain an enormous amount of non-printable characters which renders Regex useless. Those are Word 97-2003 documents.

I was using encoding latin-1 and ISO-8859-1 to open the file.

I've tried to convert the original ANSI-encoding to utf-8 using Notepad++.
I've tried encode/decode trick.
i've tried `re.sub(f'[^{re.escape(string.printable)}]', '', text)` as well.
There are still a bunch of non-printable characters there. And interestingly after all of the above mentioned manipulations python console prints the document text many times in a row (like 7 identical duplicates in a row).

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @D.L as i mentioned above: i've tried with converting with notepad++, using encode/decode function and removing the non-printable characters using regex. There's not really much more of a code i can present here which is relevant for the problem.